# I want to make this bubble sort function work but it gives me Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

```
function bubbleSort(arr) {
    var temp = arr.slice(0)
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        if (arr[i + 1] < arr[i]) {
            var temp_1 = arr[i+1]
            var temp_2 = arr[i]
            arr[i] = temp_1
            arr[i+1] = temp_2
        }
    }
    if (temp != arr) {
        return bubbleSort(arr)
    }
    return arr
}

console.log(bubbleSort([2,1,5,4,10,7,6,9,3,8]))
```

Comment: Two different arrays will **always** be `!=` to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not looking at the algorithm because I think you have it right. You're problem is the comparison between arrays. Try use this function

```
JSON.stringify(temp) !== JSON.stringify(array);
```

What's happening here is that temp != array always returns true, you can see it by adding

```
 console.log(temp !== array)
```

before the comparison.

Explaination: JSON#stringify compares two strings obtained from the array. Another way to achieve comparison is comparing the lenght and the equality of all the items one by one. If you use "!=" operator you'll always get nothing but "true" as the two arrays are two different instances of Object

Complete code

```
function bubbleSort(arr) {
var temp = arr.slice(0);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    if (arr[i + 1] < arr[i]) {
        var temp_1 = arr[i+1];
        var temp_2 = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp_1;
        arr[i+1] = temp_2;
    }
}
    if (JSON.stringify(temp) !== JSON.stringify(arr)) {
         return bubbleSort(arr);
    }
         return arr
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know that comparing those two arrays, which contain same elements and have same length, would return false always! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

1. Operators `==` and `!=` are comparing references, so they will always consider two arrays as different (unless you comparing same instance). Check `['a'] == ['a']`: it will be `false`.
   You could use flag to indicate changes was occurred:

```js
function bubbleSort(arr) {
  var temp = arr.slice(0)
  var changed = false
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
      if (arr[i + 1] < arr[i]) {
          changed = true
          var temp_1 = arr[i+1]
          var temp_2 = arr[i]
          arr[i] = temp_1
          arr[i+1] = temp_2
      }
  }
  if (changed) {
      return bubbleSort(arr)
  }
  return arr
}
```

2. As soon as you don't know length of the input array and how close it is to sorted state, you still might fall into same problem in some cases, so it's better to replace recursion by loop:

```js
function bubbleSort(arr) {
  var changed = false
  do {
    var temp = arr.slice(0)
    changed = false
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        if (arr[i + 1] < arr[i]) {
            changed = true
            var temp_1 = arr[i+1]
            var temp_2 = arr[i]
            arr[i] = temp_1
            arr[i+1] = temp_2
        }
    }
  } while (changed);
  return arr
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for elaborating the comparison and suggesting me a different way to go! I will work on using flag for while loop!